# Need helping with innerHTML and array input variables

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I need this to take user input. Take the value and subtract one so that one of the 5 arrays can be called and printed. If 5 is chosen, all 5 arrays are printed; if 3 is chosen arrays 0 through 2 are printed.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML1.0Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Test2</title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" onclick="dutyarray()" value="Click">To see my top<input type="number"     id="counter"> job duties here</input>
<br />
<p id="task">Duties</p>
<script>
function dutyarray()
{
    var x = document.getElementById('counter').value;
    x = parseInt(x);

    var duty= new Array();
    duty[0] = "Operate Equipment";
    duty[1] = "Check for Water Damage";
    duty[2] = "Check for Mold";
    duty[3] = "Follow Insurance Procedure";
    duty[4] = "Restore";        

    while(x >= 0; x - 1)
    {
        document.getElementById('task').innerHTML = duty[x] + <br>;
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Bounds-checking... Make sure `x` is greater than 0 before doing that loop!  Oh, and use `x--`...

Comment: `while(x >= 0; x - 1)` is not something while can do. Please look up “JavaScript array literals”. `<br>` probably needs to be in a string. To append, you could use `+=`, but the DOM is a much better solution.

Comment: You have so many errors...1. Do write ONLY the minimum code in your example. 2. `input` tag does not have an innerHTML attr, it is an open tag. 3. Read other comments.

Answer (score 2):

You could use

```
var duty = [
        "Operate Equipment",
        "Check for Water Damage",
        "Check for Mold",
        "Follow Insurance Procedure",
        "Restore"
    ],  
    x = parseInt( document.getElementById('counter').value, 10 );
document.getElementById('task').innerHTML = duty.slice(0, x).join('<br />');
```

---

**Notes**

- Always use the second argument (radix) when using `parseInt` or `parseFloat`.
- If `document.getElementById('counter').value` is a numerical string (like `'3'`), don't use `parseInt`. Instead, if necessary, use `+'3'` to get the number `3`.

  Only use `parseInt` if you want to parse something like `'3px'` into `3`.
- Don't use `getElementById` to get the same element at each iteration of a loop.

  Then, instead of

  ```
  for(var i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
     doSomething(document.getElementById('foo'), i);
  }
  ```

  use

  ```
  var el = document.getElementById('foo');
  for(var i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
     doSomething(el, i);
  }
  ```
- Never change `innerHTML` at each iteration of a loop, because modifying the DOM has bad performance.

  Then, instead of

  ```
  for(var i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
     element.innerHTML += someHTML(i); // n DOM modifications
  }
  ```

  use

  ```
  var html = '';
  for(var i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
     html += someHTML(i);
  }
  element.innerHTML = html; // only 1 DOM modification
  ```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML1.0Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Test2</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" onclick="dutyarray()" value="Click">To see my top
    <input type="number" id="counter"> job duties here</input>
    <br />
    <p id="task">Duties</p>
    <script>
        function dutyarray() {
            var x = document.getElementById('counter').value;
            x = parseInt(x);

            var duty =
                [
                "Operate Equipment",
                "Check for Water Damage",
                "Check for Mold",
                "Follow Insurance Procedure",
                "Restore"
                ];

            if (x > duty.length-1) x = duty.length-1;   // Performs some checking

            document.getElementById('task').innerHTML = "";
            for ( ; x >= 0; x--) {
                document.getElementById('task').innerHTML += duty[x] + "<br>";
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: A lot of good suggestions here getting closer to what i'm looking for please keep them coming.