# innerHtml form array

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

I have read this article [Need helping with innerHTML and array input variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19719626/need-helping-with-innerhtml-and-array-input-variables). But when i do this:

```
 if (errors.length > 0) {
    var htmlErrors ='';
    for (var i = 0; i < errors.length; i++) {    
        htmlErrors += errors[i];
    }
    document.getElementById("registration_errors").innerHtml = htmlErrors;
```

I get white screen. Where is my mistake?

Comment: Do you have any console error in your browser?

Comment: try adding `console.log(errors)` before `if` to see the content of errors.

Comment: innerHTML, not innerHtml

Comment: thats help thanks a lot.i need be more attentive)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try: `innerHTML` [Link](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp)

```
document.getElementById("registration_errors").innerHTML = htmlErrors;
```

Answer (score 1):

The if is not closed and this is `innerHTML` instead of `innerHtml`:

```
if (errors.length > 0) {
    var htmlErrors ='';
    for (var i = 0; i < errors.length; i++) {    
        htmlErrors += errors[i];
    }
    document.getElementById("registration_errors").innerHTML = htmlErrors;
}
```

Comment: if closed, i just not add the end quote) sorry)

Comment: Without the whole context, I have nothing else to say … `errors` exists and it's an no-empty array of string ?